# При вставке toolbar внизу и верху обрезается чаcть cardview

Tags: android, android-toolbar, cardview

Вставляю toolbar. Вверху  он  перекрывает часть cardview. Внизу  карточка  тоже  обрезается (Не видно тени и скругления). Как поправить сей недуг?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.hubble.news.activities.ReadingPostActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/reading_post_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/reading_post_card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                 />

            <TextView
                 />

            <TextView
                 />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

В `NestedScrollView` нужно добавить `marginTop` со значением:

`?android:attr/actionBarSize`

А для того что бы тень с низу не обрезалась сделать у `NestedScrollView` `layout_height = match_parent`

Comment: Сверху  помогло, а вот снизу  режет